# How can I make Quill.js support an additional url scheme for links?

Tags: javascript, quill

Quill editor only permits http://, https://, and mailto: for links.

Everything else gets replaced with "about:blank"

How can I enable Quill to permit an additional URL scheme?

Update:

The array of permitted values is in `Link.PROTOCOL_WHITELIST`: ["http", "https", "mailto", "tel"]

Can I change that from outside the library?

Comment: What do you want, for example?

Comment: For example, fmp://host.domain.com/file, which would connect to a FileMaker server if you have FileMaker Pro installed on the machine.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/quarfie/pen/abdNEoZ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prefill links with http in a Quill editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956020/how-can-i-prefill-links-with-http-in-a-quill-editor)

Comment: It's a clue... I can see in the console that Link.PROTOCOL_WHITELIST contains an array: ["http", "https", "mailto", "tel"]. I would like to add an additional protocol (fmp) to this array (preferably without editing the library). Is that possible?

Comment: note: the linked question above just adds "http://" if the beginning of the input text does not match any of the whitelisted protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

```
let Link = window.Quill.import('formats/link');

class CustomLink extends Link {

  static sanitize(url) {
    if(url.startsWith("fmp")) {
      return url
    } else {
      let value = super.sanitize(url);
      return value;
    }
  }
}
Quill.register(CustomLink);
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for primeng editor?

Answer (score 1):

The approach from @Jason Wood is really good, however I think there is a much simpler way to solve it. Just override the existing property on the `Quill` global object and add custom protocols:

```js
window.Quill.import('formats/link').PROTOCOL_WHITELIST = ['http', 'https', 'mailto', 'tel', 'radar', 'rdar', 'smb']
```

And you should be ready to go!

The default sanitizer should work with custom protocols, as it usually works for the default ones.