# Angular - How can I append http or https to hyperlink in a Quill editor?

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

When adding links with the Quill editor I must include the protocol or the link is treated as a relative link.

When someone adds a link without specifying any protocol I would like to append https:// by default so when a user types google.com it will create a link to https://google.com instead of https://example.com/google.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prefill links with http in a Quill editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956020/how-can-i-prefill-links-with-http-in-a-quill-editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
import Quill from 'quill';
const Link = Quill.import('formats/link');

// Override the existing property on the Quill global object and add custom protocols
Link.PROTOCOL_WHITELIST = ['http', 'https', 'mailto', 'tel', 'radar', 'rdar', 'smb', 'sms'];

class CustomLinkSanitizer extends Link {
    static sanitize(url: string) {
    // Run default sanitize method from Quill
    const sanitizedUrl = super.sanitize(url);

    // Not whitelisted URL based on protocol so, let's return `blank`
    if (!sanitizedUrl || sanitizedUrl === 'about:blank') return sanitizedUrl;

    // Verify if the URL already have a whitelisted protocol
    const hasWhitelistedProtocol = this.PROTOCOL_WHITELIST.some(function(protocol: string) {
        return sanitizedUrl.startsWith(protocol);
    });

    if (hasWhitelistedProtocol) return sanitizedUrl;

    // if not, then append only 'https' to not to be a relative URL
    return `https://${sanitizedUrl}`;
    }
}

Quill.register(CustomLinkSanitizer, true);
```